# How to map 2 digit tld domain name with google cloud storage bucket?

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

this issue has been solved by gae team. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10745

**Orginal**

I have regsitered `cdn.something.co.uk` and CNAME'd it to `c.storage.googleapis.com.`

now http://cdn.something.co.uk  works but whenever i access file system via php apis it gives error

Fatal error:  Invalid cloud storage bucket name 'cdn.something.co.uk'
at php\sdk\google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools.php:442

and then somewhere in files i found the following code.
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/php/sdk/google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools.php?r=400

```
private static function validateBucketName($bucket_name) {
    $valid_bucket_regex = '/^[a-z0-9]+[a-z0-9\.\-_]+[a-z0-9]+$/';
    if (preg_match($valid_bucket_regex, $bucket_name) === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    if (strpos($bucket_name, 'goog') === 0) {
      return false;
    }

    if (strlen($bucket_name) > 222) {
      return false;
    }

    $parts = explode('.', $bucket_name);
    foreach ($parts as $part) {
      if (strlen($part) < 3 || strlen($part) > 63) {
        return false;
      }
    }

    return true;
  }
```

see **strlen($part) < 3**

is there any solution or any other way to map different bucket to my domain?

Comment: According to their Bucket Name Verification criteria (https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/bucketnaming#verification), they say "Ends with a currently-recognized top-level domain, such as .com", but maybe it should be modified to allow ccTLD's, such as .co.uk . You should create an issue on the googleappengine project (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/FilingIssues?tm=3).

Comment: I have created issue for it. Please vote for it.. https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10745&can=6&q=domain&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log

Comment: I have created a patch for this issue and posted it to your logged issue (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10745#c1). We'll se if the projects owners/Google accepts it.

Comment: I wish i could find a way to overwrite it in app engine....
another hacky way is to implement protocol like gs2:// 
(which i am not gonna do)

Comment: we'll take a look - it it's our bug we'll get the fix out as soon as we can.

Comment: Plz do as soon as possible because our site is live and its hard to wait long..

Comment: The issue was marked as Fixed and Closed yesterday (https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10745).

Looks like this has now been resolved in 1.9.5

Comment: yes i knew that..thanks for affords and watching..